# Moving a string from one array to another in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, filter

I want to take a string that has letters and characters and filter out only the letters.  I then want to reuse that string and put it into an array.  How would I do that in C?
I have used `isalpha()` but only into `printf`, not into a variable.
Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>  
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    string w = "name1234";
    string new ="";
    int length = strlen(w);

    for (i=0; length > i; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(w[i]))
        {
            new = w;
        }
    }
    printf("This is the new one: %s\n", new);  //it should be 'name' not 'name1234'
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>  
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, newx;
    char w[] = "name1234";

    int length = strlen(w);

    // in C99 or greater, you can do
    // char new[length+1];
    // to get a variable-length local array, instead of using malloc
    char* new = malloc(length+1);
    if (!new)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
         return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0, newx = 0; length > i; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)w[i]))
        {
            new[newx++] = w[i];
        }
    }
    new[newx] = '\0';

    printf("This is the new one: %s\n", new);  //it should be 'name' not 'name1234'
    free(new); // this isn't necessary since all memory is freed when the program exits
               // (and it isn't appropriate if new is a local array) 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the memory :)

Comment: +1 for error checking the result of malloc, but -1 for not free-ing the pointer at the end.

Comment: Also, strlen returns a size_t, not an int.

Comment: A downvote for not freeing memory before exiting from main? That's absurd. Anyway, I added the `free` for the pedants who don't actually know the language. And the `size_t` is convertible to `int` and there's no reason not to use `int` if you know it's big enough to hold the size of the string.

Comment: BTW, Alex, if you're going to demand `size_t` for `length`, you should demand it for `i` and `newx` too ... but that's absurd and pointlessly pedantic.

Comment: It isn't personal, but your code is not correct. There is enough confusion on the asker's part without giving an incorrect answer.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds There is nothing incorrect about my code, as I have explained to you. I was a member of X3J11 and understand the C language, and in both theory and practice, far better than you do.

Comment: Thanks.  What does the unsigned char do?  Does it just make sure we don't need bytes that are negative, because we are using letters?

Comment: Speaking of wrong: If `length` were changed to `unsigned` but `i` were left as `int`, there would be an signed/unsigned comparison that compilers such as gcc would complain about. But no competent programmer declares indices like `i` as `size_t` ... there's just no point.

Comment: @Martin Yes, that's correct. Check the documentation of `isalpha` and you will see that it says that passing signed values other than EOF results in undefined behavior. Most implementations will handle it correctly, though.

Comment: @Jim - Thanks for your help.  So if I use getchar I should be ok then, is that what it means?

Comment: @Martin if you use `getchar`, you must store the result in an `int`, not a `char` (or `unsigned char`), because EOF requires an `int`. Generally, one checks for EOF *before* passing the character to `isalpha` or similar routines, and so it's safe to truncate the value to `unsigned char`. I hope that makes sense ... it's a bit difficult to explain in a comment.

Comment: @Jim I am trying to get it, but I am new to this :)

Comment: @Martin If you're happy with this (or some other) answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a simple code. Make sure that you understand every line.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char org[]="abc123defg";
    int size=sizeof(org)/sizeof(org[0]);   //size will hold the original array length 
    char* res=malloc((sizeof(char)*size)+1);  //+1 for the '\0' char that indicates end of a string
    if(!res)
        return 1; //allocation failed
    int i; int k=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(org[i])) {
            res[k]=org[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    res[k]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", res);  //now it will be abcdefg
    free(res);  //free the memory I've allocated for the result array
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sizeof function returns a size_t, not an int. Also, in C, sizeof(char) is always 1, so its inclusion is redundant. Finally, you did not free the pointer at the end of its lifespan.

Comment: I know it is 1, I just want him to understand how to determine the size of an array.

Comment: The implicit cast makes it a valid int, there is overflow only if the size_t value is too long, sizeof(org)/sizeof(org[0]) will never overflow.

Comment: Downvotes for the wrong reasons. The right reasons would be using `sizeof`, which will break as soon as the OP uses it in a real application with a pointer instead of an array, and not casting the arg of `isalpha` to `(unsigned char)`, which can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: That's wrong too, sizeof(org) is 11*sizeof(char), because org is an array.He hasn't passed this array to a function, so the array will not decay in a pointer and it's size will still be 11*sizeof(char).The user is correct, I also have seen a lot of other downvotes (also on my question) for no reason.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri You misunderstand me. In a real application, `org` would likely to be a `char*`, not an array. If the OP doesn't realize that the `sizeof/sizeof` *only* applies to arrays, not pointers, it will result in a bug ... one that we see here at SO every few days.

Comment: What do you mean for real application? I'd always prefer a static array over a dynamic array, unless I need to dynamically change it's length.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I mean an application that deals with strings of unknown length. I mean an application where the string is passed in as an argument, rather than being predefined in `main` as a test case, as here. As for static arrays, unless you're using VLA's, they impose an arbitrary length limit.

Comment: Yes but he shown to the user how to use the sizeof operator, and used it correctly. In Italy we say "dont shoot to a mosquito with a cannon".

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri it is rare to encounter static arrays. at the very least anytime you deal with user input -- console or internet -- the length is unknown at compile time. additionally a newbie is likely to generalize from a static array to `char *` so if this is not clarified upfront you are doing the newbie a disservice.

Comment: I think that this is just overthinking, after all the code is correct and what you say looks to me like irrelevant details.

Comment: "what you say looks to me like irrelevant details" -- All the worse for you.

Answer (score 1):

Define the proper data type char * and not string. You want to filter string A and put the result in B, you have to:

```
1) Create char *a[size], char *b[size];
2) iterate over the "string" A and verify if the actual position (char) meets the requirements to go to the "string" B;
3) if it does, just do b[pos_b] = a[i]; and increment the variable pos_b.
```

You have to declare pos_b because you can be in a different position in array b that the position you are in array A. Since, you are just adding to array b letters.

Answer (score 1):

This is the academic version:

```
const char* w= "name1234";
char* filteredString= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
const long length=strlen(w);
long size=0;
for(long i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    if(isalpha(w[i]))
    {
        size++;
        filteredString=(char*)realloc(filteredString, (size+1)*sizeof(char));
        filteredString[size-1]=w[i];
    }
}
filteredString[size]=0;
puts(filteredString);
```

Just to learn using realloc, but you could allocate the whole string on the stack and screw about memory usage, realloc takes CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made some little modifications to your code to make it work properly, but you could use some libs like `string.h`. I hope you understand it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    /* I limited your strings to avoid some problems. */
    char w[20]  = "name1234";
    /* The name "new" is a reserved word in C (at least in my IDE). */
    char nw[20] = "";
    int length  = strlen(w);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        /* I added the special string end character '\0'. */
        if(isalpha(w[ i ]) || w[ i ] == '\0')
        {
            nw[ j ] = w[ i ];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("This is the new one: %s\n", nw);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The strlen function returns a size_t, not an int.

Comment: @AlexReynolds you was the one who downvoted this answer because of the `size_t` ? if so, and only **if**, look around and you will see a bunch of people using `int` instead of `size_t` when using `strlen()`, even serious developers use `int`, IMHO is pointless, an string of more than 32^2-1 characters is very unlikely, a secure system should not let an user `malloc(4GB)` just like that.

Comment: @Kira Indeed. Those downvotes are uncalled for and do not reflect programming competence. As I noted on my answer, calling for `size_t` for `length` but *not* for the indices `i` and `j` is wrong and incompetent, showing no understanding of type consistency.

Comment: @JimBalter If i do `(int) strlen( )` is it considered correct?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto It's already correct, as long as the string length doesn't exceed the capacity of an `int`. Adding the cast is unnecessary and casts can hide real errors.

Comment: Also great code, like the JimBalter code.

Comment: This code is buggy because it doesn't NUL-terminate `nw`. The test for NUL inside the loop is pointless and does nothing because there can't possibly be a NUL in the first `length` chars, because `length` was obtained from `strlen`. It *would* work if the loop used `i <= length` instead of `i < length`.

Comment: An `int`'s maximum value on a 32-bit system (another assumption that isn't always true) is roughly 2.1 billion, not 4 billion, so a malloc(INT_MAX) is not the same as malloc(4GB). So that should be another warning sign about the quality of advice on display here. Be that as it may, it is bad practice to use a signed type for indexing, because of the risk of overflow. There is no such thing as a string with a negative length, and therefore no good reason to use a signed type for indexing, other than lazy assumptions that will come back and haunt you. YMMV.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Take it up with K&R and all those other good C programming books you recommend that use `int` extensively. I've been programming in C for over 35 years and using `int` for string sizes and indices has never yet haunted me.

Comment: "Be that as it may, it is bad practice to use a signed type for indexing, because of the risk of overflow. "  -- This is truly absurd. There is a risk of overflow if the integer type is not big enough to hold all the possible values; this has nothing to do with whether it is signed or not. In the case of signed types you get undefined behavior whereas in the case of unsigned types you wrap to 0, but both give wrong results. What matters is knowing the actual range of the size of the arrays you are dealing with.

Comment: Question about the>>>  if ( isalpha( w[ i ] ) || w[ i ] == '\0' <<<line, what does it do?  It compares the isalpha array with the standard array and sees if it is zero?  Why?

Comment: This tests if the `char` at `w[i]` is alphanumeric or is a null terminator. The null terminator is a special character used to mark the end of the string. This character is critical, because it tells C string functions where the string ends and therefore keeps them from going beyond the end of the string and returning garbage.

Comment: @Martin That code checks whether character `w[i]` is alphabetic OR zero (a NUL character). See my comment above ... it actually achieves nothing in the code as written, because `w[i]` cannot be a NUL character because `strlen` stops AT the NUL character that terminates the string. I think Alberto meant to include the NUL character in the string being examined, in which case the loop limit should be `i <= length`, not `i < length`.

Comment: @Martin "It compares the isalpha array with the standard array and sees if it is zero?" -- no, you're quite misunderstanding. The "isalpha array" is `nw`, which isn't mentioned in that line of code. The code is dealing with `char`'s that are *elements* of the original array, checking each one in turn to see if it is alphabetic (or zero, here).

Comment: If you are sure that the loop stops at some positive value, not even close to 100, you are sure to not overflow.